# Sumif with Array Formula + "GREATER THAN"

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I know how to use sumif with array formula in this way:
=ARRAYFORMULA(sumif(F3:F10,A3:A6,J3:I10))

But when I try to use greater than or less than signs, it doesn't work:
=ARRAYFORMULA(sumif(F3:F10&H3:H10&I3:I10,A3:A6&">"&B3:B6&"<"&B3:B6,J3:J10))

Sample: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-YaMwpq9ft3nBVwPkDOjj-L42xPtUN1gE0JZO6pS2xY/edit?usp=sharing

The purpose is to sum amount of fruits given the max amount, min amount, fruit type criteria. Tried to use sumifs, it doesn't work.

Comment: please add a column for "desired results" based on your inputs.

Comment: @MattKing Added new column.

Comment: what is the purpose of column G?

Comment: It was just for example. I've deleted it. Sorry if I mislead you.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't necessarily need to use `SUMIF`, you may try with `QUERY` instead:

#### Sample Formula (Paste it on `C3`)

```
=QUERY(F3:J10, ("select J where F = '" & A3 & "' AND " & B3 & " >= H AND " & B3 & " <= I"))
```

#### References:

- [QUERY function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [Google Query Syntax](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage)

Comment: Is it possible to make your solution work as array formula? I need an array formula.

Comment: Unfortunately, QUERY and ARRAYFORMULA don't work together in Sheets. However the answer provided by @player0 covers that approach using ARRAYFORMULA and VLOOKUP.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(A3:A6&B3:B6, {F:F&G:G, J:J}, 2, 0))
```

[image]

or:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(A3:A6&TEXT(B3:B6, "00000"), 
 SORT({F:F&FILTER(TEXT(H:H, "00000"), H:H<>""), J:J}), 2, 1))
```

[image]

Comment: What about criteria3 (max amount)? You only use Criteria2 (min amount).

Comment: @BeketKassymbekov vlookup does not need max. the next min defines previous max