# SUMIF on multiple criteria or SUMIFS with array criteria or FILTER/QUERY based on lookup table

Tags: google-sheets

The rather ridicules title covers what I have tried and failed to do this far. I'm trying to `SUM` only the  positive values for multiple account numbers.

> Minimum reproducible sample: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X1agIcfIgs6pZAqx6G7FsIgfTrx6mStxF0mJaE6UsWc/edit?usp=sharing

[image: lookup table]
*My lookup table which has the, unfortunate mixed language, named ranges, "konti" for account numbers and "kontiCategories" for account categories. This tab is named "Konti".*

I then got a list of entries, with an account number, amount etc.

[image: list of posts, with an account number, amount etc.]
*This tab is named "Postering".*

**I want to `SUM` the positive amounts, from “Postering”, that have the same account number as in my lookup table where the `kontiCategories` is equal to "Variable omkostninger".**
It should equal 100000.

The account numbers, I get from my lookup table with the category "Variable omkostninger".

```
=FILTER(konti; kontiCategories="Variable omkostninger")
```

To `SUM` all of the amounts from those two accounts, I can do:

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(accountNumbers; FILTER(konti; kontiCategories="Variable omkostninger"); amounts)))
```

But I only want the positive numbers. I have tried with `SUMIFS` but that function does not take an array as single criteria.
Below is a version of `SUMIFS` with my filter and with a hard coded array - both give the same result. E.g. 50000.

```
=SUMIFS(amounts; accountNumbers; ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER(konti; kontiCategories="Variable omkostninger")); amounts; ">0")
=SUMIFS(amounts; accountNumbers; {5808;5809}; amounts; ">0")
```

Seemingly `SUMIFS` does not take an array as criterion as `SUMIF` does.

Another way to do this would be to create a "view" of the entries and then `SUMIF` the positive numbers.

I first tried with `QUERY` but can not see how I can use my filter to select the correct entries. Rather I have to hard code the account numbers.

```
=QUERY(Postering!B1:I30; "select * where D = 5808 or D = 5809"; 1)
```

*D is the account number column.*

My last attempt was to use `MAP` and `LAMDA` but again, I run into the issue that I can not use my filter.

```
=MAP (accountNumbers;
      amounts;
      LAMBDA (accountNumber;
              amount;
              IF (
                AND (accountNumber = 
                     FILTER (konti;
                             kontiCategories="Variable omkostninger");
                     amount > 0);
                amount;
                0)))
```

*The above will give me all of the positive amounts but only for the first account number (5808).*

EDIT:

Based on the answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/72277120/205696, I tried to use my filter to create a `where` clause that can create a "view" into the entries based on my lookup table. But it is overly complicated! Hopefully there is a simpler way to do this?

```
=QUERY (
  Postering!B1:I30;
  "select * where " &
    JOIN(" or ";
      SPLIT (
        CONCATENATE (
          MAP (
            FILTER(konti;
                   Konti!C2:C15="Variable omkostninger");
            LAMBDA (account;
                    "D=" & account & ",")
          ));
        ",")
     );
  1)
```

[image: A "view" into the entries which contains only account number 5808 and 5809, which are defined as "Variable omkostning" in the lookup table.]
*A "view" into the entries which contains only account number 5808 and 5809, which are defined as "Variable omkostning" in the lookup table.*

Comment: Can you provide a minimum reproducible sample of your Google Sheets, so the community can have better chance of providing you a formula that best work for you.

Comment: I can’t today but I will do it tomorrow

Comment: @Babanana here is minimal example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X1agIcfIgs6pZAqx6G7FsIgfTrx6mStxF0mJaE6UsWc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
=sum(ifna(filter(amounts;xmatch(accountNumbers;filter(konti;kontiCategories=K1));amounts>0)))
```

- Change `Cell_K1` in the formula accordingly *OR* hardcode the value `Variable omkostninger`

[image]

Comment: Thanks @rockinfreakshow! I didn't know about `XMATCH` and reading the documentation, I wouldn't know that `search_key` could be a range. `XMATCH(search_key, lookup_range, [match_mode], [search_mode])`

Answer (score 0):

You asked for:

> I want to SUM the positive numbers from account numbers 5808 and 5809. It should equal 100000.

```
=SUM(INDEX(IF((((D2:D11=5808)+(D2:D11=5809))*(G2:G11>0)),G2:G11,"")))
```

*(**Do** adjust the formula according to your ranges and locale)*

[image]

Comment: I’m sorry! I explained poorly. I want to sum the positive amounts, that have the account numbers where the `kontiCategory` is equal to "Variable omkostninger". I will edit my question.